# programmatically taking screenshot of current screen in android device?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-screen

I am working on an app in which I have some edit texts and background image. I wrote something in that edit text, I want to save whole current screen as an image, so that I can send it via email. I got a solution using ASL(android screenshot library) but for this I have to start native service on my device every time when I reboot it. So is there any other solution to take screenshot of current screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..  find the Parent layout in you xml and do this.

```
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.layout);
     ll .setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: no avi... i wanted to include this functionality in my app, so that it can work on any device