# Taking screenshot without android Activity, Fragment or View context

Tags: android, android-fragments, screenshot, takesscreenshot

I want to take screenshot of whatever Activity, Fragment of Dialog is currently visible without the Activity, Fragment or Dialog context e.g on device shake, I do have the application context.

All of the following answers need Activity, Fragment or View.

1. [Taking screenshot programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829773/taking-screenshot-programmatically-in-android)
2. [problem in taking screenshots in android by programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552619/problem-in-taking-screenshots-in-android-by-programmatically)
3. [programmatically taking screenshot of current screen in android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815573/programmatically-taking-screenshot-of-current-screen-in-android-device)
4. [Android : taking Screenshot of the selected area programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26190852/android-taking-screenshot-of-the-selected-area-programmatically)

Comment: If you are looking to take a screenshot of arbitrary apps, use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+.

Comment: No, I want to take screenshot of my app like Instabug do without the Activity context.

Comment: Most likely, they have access to the Activity, courtesy of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Comment: This looks promising, thanks.

Comment: hey, @SohailAziz where you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes, no directly but listening to screenshot save event in gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared pref to take screenshot without android Activity, Fragment or View context